# Django: Serializer + Query Optimization

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have Django models something like below,

```
class Chef(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    chef = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ranking = models.IntegerField(default=99999)
```

and serializer clases.

```
class ChefSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    restaurant = RestaurantSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Chef
        fields = ('name', 'restaurant')

class RestaurantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = ('chef', 'location', 'ranking')
```

And I use those like this.

```
class MyView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Chef.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ChefSerializer
    ...
    def do_somthing(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset)
        calculate_something(serializer.data)
...
```

I want to optimize my queries so tried to inspect them like below.

```
...
print(queryset.query) # "SELECT chef.id, chef.name FROM chef"
...
```

But I can't find the exact query that my `RestaurantSerializer` use.

1. I want to do something like `print(restaurantserializer.data.query)`. What should I do? I want to know when and how the query related to the `Restaurant` table is executed.
2. I also want to optimize my queries into just one query like `select c.name, r.location, r.ranking FROM chef c JOIN restaurant r ON c.id=r.chef_id`

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust the queryset:

```py
res = Restaurant.objects.only('location', 'ranking').filter(chef_id=1)
```

In case that you want to fetch the name of chef, you must do:

```py
res = Restaurant.objects.select_related('chef').only('location', 'ranking', 'chef__name').filter(chef_id=1)
```

You can read more details for `select_related` and `prefetch_related` in [django website](https://www.djangoproject.com/).

A useful package to have a look in the SQL queries is the [silk](https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk).